# blocking IO in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, blocking, nonblocking

I am developing an application using NodeJS where two queries depend on each other here is explanation of my situation.

> I have to query database for some values say A then I have to query
>   database for some other value B only if there is an A in the database.

I know I can do this in NodeJS' natural way like execute query for A when its result is ready execute query for B in A's callback and then finally render response in B's callback.

Here is my question, is there a design issue in the solution I just mentioned perhaps about nested callbacks.

Second is there any method in which I can make NodeJs IO as Blocking from NON-Blocking?

Comment: If you do blocking IO, your entire program will be unable to respond to any requests at all until those queries complete. That is not usually what you want.

Comment: Node does have some I/O functions that offer both blocking and non-blocking versions - such as fs.readFile and fs.readFileSync. If your database driver offers a blocking function - you could use that. One example of when blocking might be desired is when the node app starts - since you won't be taking any requests until the initialization functions complete anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was made aware of a library called [Async](https://github.com/caolan/async) Which i wish id found when i started my NodeJs projects. It can take care of this and much more.

> Async provides around 20 functions that include the usual 'functional'
>   suspects (map, reduce, filter, each…) as well as some common patterns
>   for asynchronous control flow (parallel, series, waterfall…). All
>   these functions assume you follow the node.js convention of providing
>   a single callback as the last argument of your async function.

basic example from site that would help in your scenario

```
async.series([
    function(callback){
        // do db call one
        callback(null, 'one');
    },
    function(callback){
        // do db call two
        callback(null, 'two');
    }
],
function(err, results){
    // results is now equal to ['one', 'two']
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> Here is my question, is there a design issue in the solution I just mentioned perhaps about nested callbacks.

No, your solution is perfectly fine.

> Second is there any method in which I can make NodeJs IO as Blocking from NON-Blocking?

Yes. You can write your own c++ extension to provide blocking calls.